# Calculate max Data

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, integers

Over the last few days, I have been dealing in detail with numbers and number ranges, as well as with the conversion of a value into different number ranges.

---

[X] **Some information:**

- I got a **dataField** that includes an specific amount of dataBlobs (int N like e.g **10** or **102**, ...).
- Every single **dataBlob** can hold **16 different combination** options.
- I got a dataString like **"102"** or **"10101010"**  I want to encode in the **data field**.
- The amount of **unique characters** in dataString will be the baseValue I'm encoding from. 
  ( If **dataString** is like `"101010101"` *[2 unique chars "1", "0"]* I will encode dataString **from base 2** into **base 16**) 
  ( If **dataString** is like `"102"` *[3 unique chars "1", "0", "2"]* I will encode dataString **from base 3** into **base 16**)
- The encoding of the **dataString** into Base16 will give back a array like `["0", "15", "4", "7", "1", "1", ...]` *(all values between 0 and 15)* and for every element in the `encodedData` I will add one Blob with the specific dataValue *(see in the image below)*

---

[image]

[X] **My question:**

I'd like to **calculate the maximum length** of the `dataString` a dataField with `N` dataBlobs(16combinations) can hold.

**What is given**:

- The maximum amount of **dataBlobs** can used (N)
- The count of unique chars in dataString ( = *the base-value I will encode from*)

dataString = `"10101010"`      | (from `BASE 2` to `BASE 16`) will get [10, 10] --> **Needs 2x dataBlobs**

dataString = `"102"`           | (from `BASE 3` to `BASE 16`) will get [6] --> **Needs 1x dataBlob**

dataString = `"2143567908"`    | (from `BASE 10` to `BASE 16`) will get [7, 15, 12, 4, 4, 0, 2, 4] --> **Needs 8x dataBlobs**

---

> How can I calculate the `amount of characters` **dataString** (with a given Base value) can hold if I want to use `N` **dataBlobs**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the number of digits used to encode a nonnegative integer number $k$ in base $b$ is equal to $ \left \lceil\log_b k \right \rceil + 1$. For instance, to encode 32 in base 2, you need $\lceil \log_2 32\rceil + 1 = 5 + 1 = 6$ digits: $32_2 = 100000$.

If you want to use $N$ dataBlobs, you can encode a number that is at most equal to $16^N - 1$. It follows then that using base $b$ you will need a dataString at most $\left\lceil \log_b \left(16^N -1\right)\right\rceil + 1$ characters long.